# How to use Restkit mapping

Tags: restkit

I am using the development branch to avoid starting with the old as the new is rolling out. Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to do the basics (I am new to RestKit).

The basic steps I am trying are to accomplish start with calling "/auth/login/" with 2 parameters and retrieve a json document back. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE 1: am I asking the wrong question? what am I missing? do people just no use Restkit for projects?

UPDATE 2: what should I look for when getting this error? I have a class mapping and a path pattern, but I really don't get what I should be doing.

```
Code=1001 "Unable to find any mappings for the given content"
```

I just found this updated readme file at https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/development/README.md

UPDATE 3: I have tried a variety of ways to do a simple call/respond/success call but nothing. I can see in the output the call is successful, but RestKit always complains it cannot map the content. I really do not get it. The resulting json is mostly as follows:

```
{
      "email" : "me@here.com",
      "fullname" : "Full Name"
}
```

and no matter what I try, I cannot get RestKit to figure that out. Help? Anyone?

UPDATE 4: I changed the payload to be the following, plus I changed the descriptor statement, but there was no change in results. The call succeeds, RestKit fails for error 1001. It still says my keyPath=null. What am I missing?

```
{
    "whoami" : {
      "email" : "me@here.com",
      "fullname" : "Full Name"
    }
} 

[manager addResponseDescriptor:[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:mymap
                                               pathPattern:@"/auth/login/"
                                                   keyPath:@"whoami"
                                               statusCodes:statusCodes]];
```

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation on the github site?  https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/master/Docs/Object%20Mapping.md. Or googled for some examples?  http://liebke.github.com/restkit-github-client-example/

Comment: Most of the examples use methods that no longer exist and even some classes no longer exist such as RKClient. I have been looking for a while now, trying to get beyond the learning curve. The detailed examples seem to show one way of working but only if the server works exactly how RestKit wants the server to work. Doing something else seems really hard, mostly because its not obvious what to do. Yup, I really am confused :)

Comment: The second example you referenced I can make much of it work except the call to "RKObjectMapper* mapper = objectManager.mapper" which no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help..the request may look like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[params setObject:email forKey:@"email"];
[params setObject:fullname forKey:@"fullname"];


NSMutableURLRequest *rq = [manager requestWithObject:[User new] method:RKRequestMethodPOST path:@"http://url" parameters:params];

RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:[User mapping] pathPattern:nil keyPath:nil statusCodes:nil];

RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [[RKObjectRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:rq responseDescriptors:@[responseDescriptor]];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *result) {

     //success

} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

     //error

}];
[operation start];
```

and mapping:

```
+ (RKObjectMapping *)mapping
{
    RKObjectMapping *requestMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[self class]];
    [requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
     @"ContactDetail":     @"contactDetail",
     @"IdUser":            @"idUser",
     @"Name":              @"name",
     @"Address":           @"address",
     @"UserSettings":      @"userSettings"
     }];

    // if the obj have relationship
    RKRelationshipMapping *rl = [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"someKey" toKeyPath:@"toKey" withMapping:[Obj mapping]];
    [requestMapping addPropertyMappingsFromArray:@[rl]];

    return requestMapping;
}
```